# Control the Opacity of Multiple Leaflet Heatmap Layers

Tags: javascript, plugins, heatmap

I need to control the opacity of more than one instance of the HeatMap Layers created by leaflet.js , heatmap.

(source code https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.heat/blob/gh-pages/src/HeatLayer.js)

I found one answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25974054/control-the-opacity-of-heatmap-using-leaflet-heatmap/25999948#25999948).

It only works if I want the entire heatMap layer to change; but now the problem is I have more than one heatLayer and want to control opacity on each individual one.

I have tried using _leaflet_id because the canvas created has no id and I do not know how to assign one with this plugin.

However, when I try using _leaflet_id I get a uncaught exception "number is not a function"

The number for opacity is being set by a slider here:

```
 /*slide controls for opacity - currently on canvas object*/
          if( testID == 'oSlider' ) {
          var oHandle = ui.values[0]
          var opacityNum = (oHandle/100)

          if( comboBox === 'A' ) {
         ( aHeat._leaflet_id ).css({ "opacity":opacityNum });
          }
          else if( comboBox === 'B' ) {
         ( bHeat._leaflet_id ).css({ "opacity":opacityNum });
          }

          };
```

Any ideas on how I might control the opacity on individual heatmap canvases?

UPDATE:

Here is my attempt to traverse the DOM and set the multiple canvas objects to later change the opacity on them.  So far this only works, when the first canvas is set.  The second appears to re-write all of them all over again.

```
function addDataSet() {

var dataSourceCmb = document.getElementById("dataSourceCmb").value;

        /* A-canvas Add --- Start */    
        if(dataSourceCmb === 'A') {

            if(typeof(aHeat)==='undefined' || aHeat.undefined===true)
            {    
            aHeat = L.heatLayer(aPoints,{maxZoom:13,radius:10,blur:5,gradient: {0.2: "#FF00FF",.4: "#00FFFF" , 0.6: "#00FF00", 0.8: "#FFFF00", 1.0: "#FF0000"} })
            .addTo(map), draw= true;

                $(document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')).each(function(i, obj){

                    console.log("A Canvas Before Add:  " + $(document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')).attr('id'));

                    if ($(document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')).attr('id') != true) {
                        $(this).attr('id','aCanvas');

                     console.log("A Canvas After Add:  " + $(document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')).attr('id'));

                    }

                })  


            }

        }
        /* A-canvas Add --- End */ 

        /* B-canvas Add --- START */     
        else if(dataSourceCmb === 'B') {
            if(typeof(bHeat)==='undefined' || bHeat.undefined===true) {    
            bHeat = L.heatLayer(bPoints,{maxZoom:13,radius:10,blur:5,gradient: {0.2: "#FF00FF",.4: "#00FFFF" , 0.6: "#00FF00", 0.8: "#FFFF00", 1.0: "#FF0000"} })
            .addTo(map), draw= true;

                 $(document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')).each(function(i, obj){

                console.log("B Canvas Before Add:  " + $(document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')).attr('id'));

                 if ($(document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')).attr('id') != true) {
                    $(this).attr('id','bCanvas');

                console.log("B Canvas After Add:  " + $(document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')).attr('id'));
                   /* console.log($(document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')).attr('id'));*/
                        }

                    })

                }

        }
        /* B-canvas Add --- End */     

        /* C-canvas Add --- START */         
        else if(dataSourceCmb === 'C') {
            if(typeof(cHeat)==='undefined' || cHeat.undefined===true ){    
            cHeat = L.heatLayer(cPoints,{maxZoom:13,radius:10,blur:5,gradient: {0.2: "#FF00FF",.4: "#00FFFF" , 0.6: "#00FF00", 0.8: "#FFFF00", 1.0: "#FF0000"} })
            .addTo(map), draw= true;

                 $(document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')).each(function(i, obj){

                console.log("C Canvas Before Add:  " + $(document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')).attr('id'));

                 if ($(document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')).attr('id') != true) {
                    $(this).attr('id','cCanvas');

                console.log("C Canvas After Add:  " + $(document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')).attr('id'));
                   /* console.log($(document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')).attr('id'));*/
                        }

                    })

                }

         }    
        /* C-canvas Add --- End */


                        $(document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')).each(function(i, obj){

                        if ($(document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')).attr('id') != true) {
                            console.log("no canvas id set for canvas: "+i);
                                }
                        else {
                            console.log($(document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')).attr('id')+" canvas no: "+i);
                        }

                            })   

                        console.log("aCanvas width: " + document.getElementById("aCanvas").width)
                        console.log("bCanvas width: " + document.getElementById("bCanvas").width)
                        console.log("cCanvas width: " + document.getElementById("cCanvas").width)


}
```

When aCanvas is set it fails the $(document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')).attr('id') != true test, but I get a width back and the opacity slider I made controls the opacity.  However, when bCanvas is set; it re-names aCanvas, and fails the id test on both canvases, and gives a width for bCanvas.  Then the opacity slider complains that aCanvas is null and does not set any values.

Not sure what i'm doing wrong here.

Here is the slider control btw:

```
 <script>

            /* adjust intesity, radius, blur based on zoom-level; it should be more intense at higher zoom levels */
            /* maxZoom: the lower the number the more intense (gives the zoom level to be the maximum intensity */    
            /* radius: the radius of each point; the more they overlap the more intense the color */
            /* blur: the amount of blurring to each point to allow for more overlap; the larger the more blur */

    $(document).ready(function() {


      $( ".slider-vertical" ).each(function(){

          $this = $(this);

          $(".slider",$this).slider({
          orientation: "horizontal",
          range: "min",
          min: 0,
          max: 100,
          values: [60],
          slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $(this).parent().find(".amount").html(  ui.values[0] );
              var testID = $(this).attr('id')

              var dataSourceCmb = document.getElementById("dataSourceCmb").value


/*slide controls for radius  (range 0.55-50.55) */

/*slide controls for maxZoom/aka Intensity (range 4-24) */

/*slide controls for blur*/

              /*slide controls for opacity - currently on canvas object*/
              if( testID == 'oSlider' ) {

              var oHandle = ui.values[0]
              var opacityNum = (oHandle/100)
                  if( dataSourceCmb === 'A' ){
                  document.getElementById("aCanvas").style.opacity=opacityNum; 
                      console.log(document.getElementById("aCanvas").style.opacity);
                  }
                  else if( dataSourceCmb === 'B' ){
                  document.getElementById("bCanvas").style.opacity=opacityNum; 
                  }
                  else if( dataSourceCmb === 'C' ){
                  document.getElementById("cCanvas").style.opacity=opacityNum;  
                  }
              };


/* slide controls for hue */


          }
         });

        $( "#amount" ).html( $( ".slider" ).slider( "values",0 ) );

      }); 

    });



    </script>
```

Here are the html controls btw:

```
<div id="sliderControls" class="leaflet-control">
    <div id="rParent" class="slider-vertical">
          <b style="margin-left:100px">Radius:</b>
          <span id="radius" class="amount">0</span>
          <div id="rSlider" class="slider"></div> 
     </div>

    <div id="iParent" class="slider-vertical">
          <b style="margin-left:100px">Intensity:</b>
          <span id="intensity" class="amount">0</span>
          <div id="iSlider" class="slider"></div> 
     </div>

    <div id="bParent" class="slider-vertical">
          <b style="margin-left:100px">Blur:</b>
          <span id="blur" class="amount">0</span>
          <div id="bSlider" class="slider"></div> 
     </div> 

    <div id="oParent" class="slider-vertical">
          <b style="margin-left:100px">Opacity:</b>
          <span id="opacity" class="amount">0</span>
          <div id="oSlider" class="slider"></div> 
     </div>

    <div id="hParent" class="slider-vertical">
          <b style="margin-left:100px">Hue:</b>
          <span id="hue" class="amount">0</span>
          <div id="hSlider" class="slider"></div> 
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: btw, my sliders have a min:0 and max:100.  I can change those if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the answer was more layers of separation and proper order of operations.  I had to add ids to each canvas after they were added to the map because the [leaflet-heat.js](http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.heat/dist/leaflet-heat.js) is not a traditional layer.  Rather, it is a class and does not include access to the setOpacity() method from leaflet and creates each instance of the heatmap as a identical canvas without a id or ability to set the id.  Then I could call the changes to the canvas ids at runtime.  Since I'm controlling the opacity via a slider, I'm also including the slider header script and body html to help out whomever may want to do the same thing in the future.

JS:

```
    function addDataSet() {

    var dataSourceCmb = document.getElementById("dataSourceCmb").value;

            /* permit Add --- Start */    
            if(dataSourceCmb === "Permits") {

                if(typeof(PermitHeat)==="undefined" || PermitHeat.undefined===true)
                {    
                PermitHeat = L.heatLayer(PermitsPoints,{maxZoom:13,radius:10,blur:5,gradient: {0.2: "#FF00FF",.4: "#00FFFF" , 0.6: "#00FF00", 0.8: "#FFFF00", 1.0: "#FF0000"} })
                .addTo(map), draw= true;
                }

                        }
            /* permit Add --- End */ 

            /* rig Add --- START */     
            else if(dataSourceCmb === "Rigs") {
                if(typeof(RigHeat)==="undefined" || RigHeat.undefined===true) {    
                RigHeat = L.heatLayer(RigsPoints,{maxZoom:13,radius:10,blur:5,gradient: {0.2: "#FF00FF",.4: "#00FFFF" , 0.6: "#00FF00", 0.8: "#FFFF00", 1.0: "#FF0000"} })
                .addTo(map), draw= true;
                }
                        }
            /* rig Add --- End */     

            /* branch Add --- START */         
            else if(dataSourceCmb === "Branches") {
                if(typeof(BranchHeat)==="undefined" || BranchHeat.undefined===true ){    
                BranchHeat = L.heatLayer(BranchesPoints,{maxZoom:13,radius:10,blur:5,gradient: {0.2: "#FF00FF",.4: "#00FFFF" , 0.6: "#00FF00", 0.8: "#FFFF00", 1.0: "#FF0000"} })
                .addTo(map), draw= true;
                }
                          }    
            /* branch Add --- End */


        var theCanvases = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas");

        /* setting canvas Ids */


         for (var i=0; i < theCanvases.length; i++) {   
           /* console.log("Type of attr id: " + typeof($(document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")).attr("id")) ); */



            var myCanvas = theCanvases[i];
            var attr = $(myCanvas).attr("id");


            setTimeout(function(){

           /* console.log( myCanvas );*/
            /* console.log( attr ); */

            if( typeof(attr) === "undefined") {

            /*console.log("this attr id: " + $(myCanvas).attr("id"));*/

                if(dataSourceCmb === "Permits") {
                    $(myCanvas).attr("id","pCanvas");
                }
                else if(dataSourceCmb ==="Rigs") {
                    $(myCanvas).attr("id","rCanvas");
                }
                else if(dataSourceCmb ==="Branches") {
                    $(myCanvas).attr("id","bCanvas");
                }

            } 


         },500)       


         }






    }
```

Slider Script (in header):

```
    <script>

            /* adjust intesity, radius, blur based on zoom-level; it should be more intense at higher zoom levels */
            /* maxZoom: the lower the number the more intense (gives the zoom level to be the maximum intensity */    
            /* radius: the radius of each point; the more they overlap the more intense the color */
            /* blur: the amount of blurring to each point to allow for more overlap; the larger the more blur */

    $(document).ready(function() {


      $( ".slider-vertical" ).each(function(){

          $this = $(this);

          $(".slider",$this).slider({
          orientation: "horizontal",
          range: "min",
          min: 0,
          max: 100,
          values: [60],
          slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $(this).parent().find(".amount").html(  ui.values[0] );
              var testID = $(this).attr('id')

              var dataSourceCmb = document.getElementById("dataSourceCmb").value


              /*slide controls for radius  (range 0.55-50.55) */


              /*slide controls for maxZoom/aka Intensity (range 4-24) */


            /*slide controls for blur*/


              /*slide controls for opacity - currently on canvas object*/
              if( testID == 'oSlider' ) {

              var oHandle = ui.values[0]
              var opacityNum = (oHandle/100)
                  if( dataSourceCmb === 'Permits' ){
                  document.getElementById("pCanvas").style.opacity=opacityNum; 
                      /*console.log(document.getElementById("pCanvas").style.opacity);*/
                  }
                  else if( dataSourceCmb === 'Rigs' ){
                  document.getElementById("rCanvas").style.opacity=opacityNum; 
                  }
                  else if( dataSourceCmb === 'Branches' ){
                  document.getElementById("bCanvas").style.opacity=opacityNum;  
                  }
              };


             /*slide controls for hue*/




          }
         });

        $( "#amount" ).html( $( ".slider" ).slider( "values",0 ) );





      }); 

    });



    </script>
```

html body slider div:

```
    <div id="sliderControls" class="leaflet-control">


        <div id="oParent" class="slider-vertical">
              <b style="margin-left:100px">Opacity:</b>
              <span id="opacity" class="amount">0</span>
              <div id="oSlider" class="slider"></div> 
         </div>


    </div>
```

Combo Box for the dataSourceCmb:

```
<div id="datasourceContent" class="leaflet-control">
    <div>
        <h1 class="header">Data Sets</h1>
        <br>
        <div class="ui-widget">
            <label>Choose a Dataset:</label>
            <select id="dataSourceCmb" >
                <option value="">Select one...</option>
                <option value="Permits">Permits</option>
                <option value="Rigs">Rigs</option>
                <option value="Branches">Branches</option>
                </select>

        </div>
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button id="addDataBtn" type="button" onClick="addDataSet()">
                <span></span>Add Dataset to Map</button>

            <button id="removeDataBtn" type="button" onClick="removeDataSet()">
                <span></span>Remove Dataset from Map</button>
            <br>
            <br>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Btw, I realize that it would be a more elegent solution to not have to name the comboBox values and then loop through them to set opacity; but this is the quick and dirty way.  Also, it helps demonstrate what exactly is being changed and when.