# adjust heatmap opacity in Folium with Python (without CSS)

Tags: python, heatmap, opacity, folium

I'm using Python only and would like to adjust the heatmap's maximum opacity. As you can see in the image below, the base map is quite invisible. **I want to see more of the base map.** How do I adjust the parameters in the `HeatMap` so that I can increase the opacity of the heatmap layer using only Python?

[image: This is the result]

it's quite the same problem in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25974054/control-the-opacity-of-heatmap-using-leaflet-heatmap), but it uses leaflet.js and the solution is using CSS, not Python. Anyway, here's my code I used to produce the map.

```
import folium
from folium import plugins
from folium.plugins import HeatMap
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("the_data.csv") # the data contains lat and long columns, I can't share the data...

coords = [(lat, lng) for lat, lng in zip(restaurants[0].lat.to_list(), restaurants[0].lon.to_list())]

m = folium.Map([-6.204725,106.847009], tiles="CartoDB dark_matter", zoom_start=14)

HeatMap(coords, 
        min_opacity=0.4,
        max_val = 0.5,
        gradient={.2: '#482d61', .5:"#5aa7d6", 1: '#fffaad'}).add_to(folium.FeatureGroup(name='Heat Map').add_to(m))
folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)

m.save("heatmap.html")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried with other tiles and other gradient colors ?

The current tile option you are using don't seem useful if you want urban details. I suggest you use `'OpenStreetMap'` or `'Cartodb Positron'` with regular gradient colors.

Is gives something like this, where you can see some urban informations :

```
m = folium.Map([48., 5.], tiles='OpenStreetMap', zoom_start=6)

HeatMap(data, min_opacity=0.4.add_to(m)
```

[image: ExampleHeatMap]

If you want to stick with the tile you are using, I can suggest you to use the blur parameter.

Exemple with default `blur = 15`

```
m = folium.Map([48., 5.], tiles='CartoDB dark_matter', zoom_start=6)
HeatMap(data, min_opacity=0.4, blur = 15, gradient={.2: '#482d61', .5:"#5aa7d6", 1: '#fffaad'}).add_to(folium.FeatureGroup(name='Heat Map')).add_to(m)
```

[image]

Example with `blur = 30`

```
m = folium.Map([48., 5.], tiles='CartoDB dark_matter', zoom_start=6)
HeatMap(data, min_opacity=0.4, blur = 30, gradient={.2: '#482d61', .5:"#5aa7d6", 1: '#fffaad'}).add_to(folium.FeatureGroup(name='Heat Map')).add_to(m)
```

[image]

Of course, the bigger the blur parameter, the more difficult it can be to interpret the data. As I don't know your objective, I'll let you decide what best suits you.

Comment: Shouldn't your first block of code contain an extra ")" before ".add_to(m)?